# how to set focus back to the combo box after pressing tab key in the same?

Tags: java

When i type invalid value(validated by me) in a combo box and CLICK(important) some other combo box or text box,its showing the message dialog(having OK button only) indicating invalid value and after clicking on OK button it sets the focus back to the combo which is Correct BUT when i press TAB key in combo box after entering the invalid value, it shows me the same message dialog but after clicking on OK button its keeps me showing the same message dialog and goes to infinite loop. so i want to know how to handle the tab event in combo box to set the focus back to combo box after entering the invalid value

Comment: Can you please provide some code that does reproduce your problem? Please make it short, ideally create a new test class with as little code as possible, but which will still does recreate your problem, and then post that code here.

Comment: Not possiible for me to isolate that code...its too big and complex please give your logic to resolve this issue :(